# Date based entry event not working

Tags: journeybuilder, contact, date

I've set-up a data based entry event as can be seen in the picture. 
When I run a similar query it gives me the people who have their birthday today.
But the entry event is not doing anything, it is not injecting any people.

Is there something else that I need to do in order for this to work?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The recommendation would be to create your entry audience as a standard data extension, either filtering from your main data extension where the anniversary of the birth date = Today (account time zone) or using SQL.

Then have Automation Studio refresh the data extension daily and use it as the entry source, instead of a date-based event.